# Heroku run rake db:migrate error: citext extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I am trying to do `heroku run rake db:migrate` but gives me this error below. Rails version is 4.2.1 (doesn't require "activerecord-postgresql-citext" gem). I added citext extension as well. In postgres table, citext search works as usual but heroku upload is not working.

On my local server rails app works fine too and the app itself has been uploaded to heroku server as well.

```
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Migrating to CreateCosingAnnexIis (20170315005057)
   (1.1ms)  BEGIN
== 20170315005057 CreateCosingAnnexIis: migrating =============================
-- create_table(:cosing_annex_iis)
   (1.6ms)  CREATE TABLE "cosing_annex_iis" ("id" serial primary key, "reference_number" integer, "chemical_name_inn" citext, "cas_number" text, "ec_number" text, "regulation" text, "regulated_by" text, "other_directives_regulations" text, "sccs_opinions" text, "chemical_iupac_name" citext, "identified_ingredients_or_substances" citext, "cmr" text, "update_date" timestamp, "created_at" timestamp DEFAULT 'now()' NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp DEFAULT 'now()' NOT NULL) 
PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "citext" does not exist
LINE 1: ..., "reference_number" integer, "chemical_name_inn" citext, "c...
                                                             ^
: CREATE TABLE "cosing_annex_iis" ("id" serial primary key, "reference_number" integer, "chemical_name_inn" citext, "cas_number" text, "ec_number" text, "regulation" text, "regulated_by" text, "other_directives_regulations" text, "sccs_opinions" text, "chemical_iupac_name" citext, "identified_ingredients_or_substances" citext, "cmr" text, "update_date" timestamp, "created_at" timestamp DEFAULT 'now()' NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp DEFAULT 'now()' NOT NULL) 
   (1.0ms)  ROLLBACK
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "citext" does not exist
LINE 1: ..., "reference_number" integer, "chemical_name_inn" citext, "c...
                                                             ^
: CREATE TABLE "cosing_annex_iis" ("id" serial primary key, "reference_number" integer, "chemical_name_inn" citext, "cas_number" text, "ec_number" text, "regulation" text, "regulated_by" text, "other_directives_regulations" text, "sccs_opinions" text, "chemical_iupac_name" citext, "identified_ingredients_or_substances" citext, "cmr" text, "update_date" timestamp, "created_at" timestamp DEFAULT 'now()' NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp DEFAULT 'now()' NOT NULL) 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:208:in `create_table'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
/app/db/migrate/20170315005057_create_cosing_annex_iis.rb:3:in `change'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:360:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "citext" does not exist
LINE 1: ..., "reference_number" integer, "chemical_name_inn" citext, "c...
                                                             ^
: CREATE TABLE "cosing_annex_iis" ("id" serial primary key, "reference_number" integer, "chemical_name_inn" citext, "cas_number" text, "ec_number" text, "regulation" text, "regulated_by" text, "other_directives_regulations" text, "sccs_opinions" text, "chemical_iupac_name" citext, "identified_ingredients_or_substances" citext, "cmr" text, "update_date" timestamp, "created_at" timestamp DEFAULT 'now()' NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp DEFAULT 'now()' NOT NULL) 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:208:in `create_table'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
/app/db/migrate/20170315005057_create_cosing_annex_iis.rb:3:in `change'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:360:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "citext" does not exist
LINE 1: ..., "reference_number" integer, "chemical_name_inn" citext, "c...
                                                             ^
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:208:in `create_table'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
/app/db/migrate/20170315005057_create_cosing_annex_iis.rb:3:in `change'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:360:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This migration file has no problem:

```
class CreateIngredients < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
  enable_extension 'citext'

  create_table :ingredients do |t|
    t.citext :name
    t.string :name_href
    t.string :overall_hazard
    t.string :cancer
    t.string :developmental
    t.string :allergies
    t.string :restrictions
    t.string :other_concerns
    t.string :animals
    t.string :score
    t.citext :synonyms, array: true, default: []
    t.timestamps null: false
  end
end
```

end

This migration file is causing the problem:

```
class CreateCosingAnnexIis < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
  create_table :cosing_annex_iis do |t|
    t.integer :reference_number
    t.citext :chemical_name_inn
    t.text :cas_number
    t.text :ec_number
    t.text :regulation
    t.text :regulated_by
    t.text :other_directives_regulations
    t.text :sccs_opinions
    t.citext :chemical_iupac_name
    t.citext :identified_ingredients_or_substances
    t.text :cmr
    t.datetime :update_date

    t.timestamps null: false, default: "now()"
  end
end
```

end

Comment: ca you share your migration page?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate

Comment: I've checked that answer but didn't solve my problem. I edited my question to include the migration page.

Comment: @Anand or do I have to include "enable_extension 'citext'" in every migration file?

Comment: why dn't you try this
`enable_extension("citext") ` and `create_table :ingredients, :force => true do |t|`